# Retrofit returns null, expecting string?

Tags: android, get, gson, retrofit

I'm a complete Android beginner. Below are the various components. Overall, I'm trying to get the value at a column (entered as a parameter) given a username.

```
Call<DefaultResponse> call2 = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getInformation("fullname","billy@gmail.com");

    call2.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call2, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {

            String informationReturned = response.body().getMsg();
            textView.append("\n"+informationReturned);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call2, Throwable t) {

        }


    });
```

The DefaultResponse class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class DefaultResponse {

    @SerializedName("error")
    private boolean err;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String msg;

    public DefaultResponse(boolean err, String msg) {
        this.err = err;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public boolean isErr() {
        return err;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

The get call

```
@GET("getInformation/{field}/{username}")
Call<DefaultResponse> getInformation(@Path("field") String field, @Path("username") String username);
```

The weird part is the PHP code works fine, as confirmed by Postman when I entered GET command http://localhost/MyApi/public/getInformation/fullname/billy@gmail.com

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! I don't really know how to get psat this and I've been troubleshooting for hours :(

Comment: I think it happens because it's a localhost.

Comment: So if I tried with remoteMySQL, would it work?

Comment: Just tried, it didn't change anything. POST requests still work (I can add users to the database, but this get still doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

you said you are expecting a string so you could use call with the String type directly in this way.

```
Call<String> call2 = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getInformation("fullname","billy@gmail.com");

call2.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call2, Response<String> response) {

        String informationReturned = response.body().getMsg();
        textView.append("\n"+informationReturned);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call2, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

you can get call like this

```
    @GET("getInformation/{field}/{username}")
Call < String > getInformation(@Path("field") String field, @Path("username") String username);
```

Comment: Doesn't really change anything. Tried it, it still doesn't give me anything as a result.

Comment: try using another simple api and check if its problem from your PHP or from the code.Meanwhile let me check if i can help you out better. And the way i told you to do, you dont need to have a DefaultResponse class for it